# Use cid in sqlite instead of column name?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

When creating a view, the name assigned to a column is not always usable in sqlite, in order to perform a specific operation afterwards.
For instance, I created the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS 
  SELECT amount, count(name), name 
    FROM mytable 
GROUP BY name 
  HAVING count(name) > 1;
```

Then I would like to do the following operation:

```
SELECT total(amount*count(name))
  FROM myview;
```

Unfortunately, count(name) is the name given by sqlite to the second column, hence, cannot be used in a select statement.
the `PRAGMA table_info(myview)` shows us that the cid to count(name) is 1, is there anyway to use this information to be able to do some computation on that column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a column alias:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS 
  SELECT amount, 
         COUNT(name) AS name_count, 
         name 
    FROM mytable 
GROUP BY name 
  HAVING count(name) > 1;
```

Then, you'll be able to use:

```
SELECT SUM(v.amount * v.name_count)
  FROM myview v;
```

I changed out `total` for `SUM`, which is more consistent with other databases ([SQLite aggregate functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html)).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT total(amount*"count(name)")
  FROM myview;
```

works as well.  It's far better to alias the column when you can, as user above indicated.

However, sometimes you're in a bind and don't have that luxury.  If you quote the name, you can use it as is.